# Accessing data in java from JSON-Ld

Tags: java, rdf, jena, json-ld

my server is receiving different JSON-LD messages as a string. I now need to acces these messages. Here is an example:

```
    {
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@graph": [
        {
          "@id": "InterIoTMsg:meta/b453273f-36d6-49a2-82ec-d909d8e6f10a",
          "@type": [
            "InterIoTMsg:meta",
            "InterIoTMsg:Observation"
          ],
          "InterIoTMsg:ReceiverPlatformId": {
            "@id": "http://om2m.org/myPlatform"
          },
          "InterIoTMsg:conversationID": "conv614d3621-7399-45b1-bf2f-505b24045ea6",
          "InterIoTMsg:dateTimeStamp": "2018-01-15T21:49:00.655+01:00",
          "InterIoTMsg:messageID": "msg7713aa0f-61df-471d-beec-80e8fb71528a"
        }
      ],
      "@id": "InterIoTMsg:metadata"
    },
    {
      "@graph": [
        {
          "@id": "_:b1",
          "@type": "sosa:Observation",
          "iiot:hasName": "tempOutside",
          "sosa:resultTime": {
            "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime",
            "@value": "2018-04-06T12:36:12Z"
          },
          "sosa:hasResult": {
            "@id": "_:b2"
          },
          "sosa:madeBySensor": {
            "@id": "_:b0"
          }
        },
        {
          "@id": "_:b2",
          "@type": "sosa:Result",
          "iiot:hasResultValue": {
            "@type": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long",
            "@value": "32"
          },
          "iiot:hasUnit": {
            "@id": "sweet_units:celsius"
          }
        },
        {
          "@id": "http://localhost:8080/weather/station1",
          "@type": "http://inter-iot.eu/GOIoTP#IoTDevice",
          "InterIoT:GOIoTP#hasName": "Weather Station 1"
        },
        {
          "@id": "_:b0",
          "@type": "sosa:Sensor",
          "sosa:isHostedBy": {
            "@id": "http://localhost:8080/in-name/humidity"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@id": "InterIoTMsg:payload"
    }
  ],
  "@context": {
    "InterIoTMsg": "http://inter-iot.eu/message/",
    "InterIoT": "http://inter-iot.eu/",
    "sosa": "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/",
    "iiot": "http://inter-iot.eu/GOIoTP#"
  }
}
```

I don't know exactly how to access specific values in the data. For example **value** in **iiot:hasResultValue**. What I have right now is a RDF-Parser which parses the `String` to a `dataset` with the help of the Jena Api:

```
try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        RDFParser.create()
                .source(in)
                .lang(Lang.JSONLD)
                .parse(dataset.asDatasetGraph());
    }
```

First of all I don't know how to continue at this point, and second I don't even know if this is the right rudiment. So if anybody could help I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

From the description, you probably want the RDF data in a model then use the model API to access the data in the model.

The first thing to try is print as Turtle so you can see the structure of the RDF.

```
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
RDFDataMgr.read(model, new StringReader(message), null, Lang.JSONLD);
RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, Lanmg.TURTLE);
```

The `RDFDataMgr.read` can also be done with:

```
RDFParser.create().fromString(message).lang(Lang.JSONLD).parse(model);
```

Comment: ideally, this should be done in dotNetRDF, nu?. Do you know the status of updates for that tool? The last release did not handle either RDFa or JSON-LD. RDFa is less important now, but JSON-LD is very important. The alternative is to use one of the conversion tools. But conversion tool output can be wobbly.

Comment: ignore the above. the new release (2.0.1) does support JSON-LD.